# unable to delete/mark-read emails

Tags: linux, postfix, plesk

I think there is something wrong with the folder-path configuration, but I am unaware how to solve this. I can send/recieve mails over IMAP with my mail applications, but no emails will go marked as read or be deleted. My guess is it has something to do with the folder path configuration, but I don't know how to get the right configuration for my postfix server.

I also have afterlogic webmail interface installed, and this interface has no problems deleting the emails or marking them read. When I do this through afterlogic it pushes through to the mail applications on my devices, but not the other way around :/

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue, and I managed to solve it like this: I use qmail, so I looked up on the log file:

```
tail -f /usr/local/psa/var/log/maillog
```

And I found lots of messages like these:

```
Apr 11 17:43:26 vpsXXXXX courier-imapd: Maximum connection limit reached for ::ffff:IPADDRESS
```

So I went to the config file:

```
nano /etc/courier-imap/imapd
```

and edited this line:

```
#
#  Maximum number of connections to accept from the same IP address

MAXPERIP=20
```

(you can play around with this setting and others on the file - just be careful).
Then you only have to restart the server:

```
/etc/init.d/courier-imaps restart
/etc/init.d/courier-imapd restart
```

And you're good to go. Hope it helps.